# Covering region with approximating squares

Tags: algorithm

I'm  trying to to write the program, that will plot region that satisifies system of inequalities.

I now have binary image with 0's and 1's.

Due to some specific implementation, I can't just draw region pixel by pixel.

Is there some algorithm, that can help to cover region by approximating rectangles/polygons?

Matrix looks like this: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling#mediaviewer/File:Screenshot-Pixel_Region_(Figure_1).png](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling#mediaviewer/File%3aScreenshot-Pixel_Region_%28Figure_1%29.png)

I need to paint 1's and leave 0's as it is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you need an efficient algorithm giving the region not by pixels but by larger rectangles. This does not look easy from a general point of view. Can you give us properties of the input? Examples at least?

Comment: Edited. I added image, how my input looks like.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5813015/47984 should solve this nicely, though not necessarily optimally.  It works a little bit harder than necessary because it avoids ever finding rectangles that overlap -- but I suspect you don't want too much overlap anyway (since that could be even more wasteful than drawing each pixel separately but once only).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm for finding the fewest rectangles to cover a set of rectangles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919298/algorithm-for-finding-the-fewest-rectangles-to-cover-a-set-of-rectangles)